# check if target element is first element in class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-traversal, jquery-traversing

I need to check if the element targeted is first element in its class and perform actions accordingly.

For eg. I have a select element with class name 'team'.

Now I need to check if the selected element is whether a first element or not.

Here's my HTML:

Initially there's a single select and checkbox input. On clicking a button, more select and checkbox inputs are added.

```
<div class="col-sm-7" id="include-fields">
   <select name="team[]" class="form-control team" id="team">
     <option></option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
   </select>

   <label>Lead</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="lead_check[]">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-offset-2">
    <button id="includes" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Dynamic `select` and `checkbox` generating:

```
$('#includes').click(function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#include-fields').append('<div class="holder-includes"><a href="#" class="remove-includes"><i class="fa fa-trash-o pull-right"></i></a>' +
    '<select name="team[]" class="form-control team">'+
    '<input type="checkbox" name="lead_check[]"></div>');

  var items = "";
  $.post("teamFetch", function(data)
  {
    $.each(data,function(index,item) 
    {
      items+="<option value='"+item.id+"'>"+item.title+"</option>";
    });

    $(".team:last").html(items); 
  }, "json");

});
```

I tried following, but no luck:

```
$(document).on("change",".team",function(e){
  var target = $(e.target);
  if(target.is(".team:first"))
  {
    $(this).parent('div#include-fields').find("input[name='lead_check[]']").val($(this).val());
  }
  $(this).siblings("input[name='lead_check[]']").val($(this).val());
});
```

Here, first `select` element is already there, but other `select` elements are added dynamically later. They all have the same class `team`.

Comment: By "first" you mean "first by creation moment" or "first by order in which it appears in the DOM"?

Comment: You might want to add some HTML as an example to illustrate what exactly you want to select for.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca first by order in which it appears in the DOM. but both is correct in my case.

Comment: Can you please share your HTML code? @Azima

Comment: I would suggest you add additional (data-) attributes to your Elements.
Would make it less "complex".

But as the previous speaker said, you might want to add some HTML/code that explains your problem.

Comment: The code that checks for first element is correct. Something could be wrong _inside_ the `if` statement.

Comment: @SmitRaval   I have edited the post. please review.

Comment: Wait a minute... are you trying to "check" the first checkbox?

Comment: Check my answer below. @Azima

Comment: @SalmanA yes.. I want to assign a value to checkbox with a value of select element's value that is closer to it. It is working fine with other dynamically generated checkboxes, but not with the first one since it's DOM traversal is a bit different with the rest of others.

Comment: @Azima Looking at the markup I think the same code `$(this).siblings("input[name='lead_check[]']")...` can be used for either case. You don't need special handling for first select.

Comment: @SalmanA yes.. but I want to fetch the required value differently with the first element

Answer (score 0):

To check if the select element is a first child of its parent among all the sibling you can use this script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("change","#include-fields .team:first",function(){
     alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Alert will only get triggered on the first select element. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/8hy34jtx/4/)